# SSRS Multiple Lines of data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

My SQL Server 2008 report returns me multiple lines in a table.  A simple select statement returns two columns, one is the record number the other is a sector.  The sector column can contain any one of 6 different values.

EDIT: `NULL` values are allowed in the sector column.

I want this data to be in one line in my table.

Lets say record number 1 has Sector A, Sector C and Sector E
and Record 2 has Sector B and Sector C
And Record 3 has none.

I am after three lines of data.  I also need it displayed two ways.  One so that all sectors appear in the same cell separated by commas.  The other is a separate Cell for each category

```
Record number  | Sector
1              | A, C, E
2              | B, C
3              |
```

Or

```
Record Number | Sector A | Sector B | Sector C | Sector D | Sector E
1             |  A       |          | C        |          | E
2             |          | B        | C        |          | 
3             |          |          |          |          |
```

At the moment my report gives me 6 rows.

```
Record Number | Sector
1             | A
1             | C
1             | E
2             | B
2             | C
3             |
```

Is there a way of working around this problem?

I am using the query designer rather than writing the SQL statements.

Comment: Please make clear what your final query result should look like. Not sure what you mean when you say you need it "two ways". Two separate queries or combined into one result.  Also, not sure what you mean when you use commas. Is that a column separator or separating multiple items in a list?

Comment: Read up on PIVOT queries in SQL Server and report back afterwards.

Comment: How many rows are in the original table? The single row that you want as the final result could be very very very long.

Comment: Does the edit help above?  Sorry about the dots spacing out.

Comment: One row per unique record number

Comment: Is there any reason you're looking to avoid writing SQL statements? A lot of this *probably could* be achieved at the report level, but there are still aspects that will be challenging and more easily solved at the query level. Also, can you please confirm whether the SSRS version is 2008 or 2008R2?

Comment: One question specifically about the data... In your data is there a set amount of Sectors? In your example, you're including Sector D, but it's not in your dataset. Is there a predefined set here?

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the first result that you want with the comma-separated list of `sector` values, you will want to use `FOR XML PATH` and `STUFF`.  The code will be:

```
select t1.recordnumber,
  STUFF((SELECT ', ' + t2.sector
         from yourtable t2
         where t1.recordnumber = t2.recordnumber
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS Sector
from yourtable t1
group by t1.recordnumber
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/01192/2). The result is:

```
| RECORDNUMBER |   SECTOR |
---------------------------
|            1 |  A, C, E |
|            2 |     B, C |
|            3 |   (null) |
```

Then to get the result of the `recordNumber` in a single row, you can use the `PIVOT` function:

```
select *
from
(
  select recordNumber, sector
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  max(sector)
  for sector in (A, B, C, D, E)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c340d/14). The result of this query is:

```
| RECORDNUMBER |      A |      B |      C |      D |      E |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|            1 |      A | (null) |      C | (null) |      E |
|            2 | (null) |      B |      C | (null) | (null) |
|            3 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
```

Comment: Can something like this be done within Query Designer say with a calculated field?

Comment: @user1957907 You should be able to place these queries in the query designer.

Comment: Hi  The downside of that is that you have to stick with the programming side of of Query Designer if you come to change the report in the future.  I was thinking maybe I could do a calculated field or something especially on table 2?

Comment: @user1957907 The second version with the `PIVOT` can be implemented using dynamic SQL to account for an unknown number of sectors.